# How to compare 'CBCharacteristic.uuid == "String"' in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to compare this? uuid and string cant compare

```
 func charValues()
 {
     let charValue = String(data: getCharacteristic.value!, encoding: 
       String.Encoding.ascii)!
     if getCharacteristic.uuid == "Manufacturer Name String"
     {
        self.lblManufactureName.text = charValue
     }
 }
```

Comment: <CBCharacteristic: 0x315382c0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = <3d414d48 53454428 208843>, notifying = NO>

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you want the string representation of the characteristic uuid then `uuidString` is the correct function but this will give you the underlying well-known uuid. There is no way of getting the interpreted value of the well known uuid apart from pulling apart the `description` string.

Comment: in CBCharacteristic UUID = Manufacturer Name String , but result is false every time.

Comment: What do you see if you log `getCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString`?

Comment: log---> Manufacturer Name String

Comment: Then that is the value you will need to look for; unless there are some hidden/unprintable characters there.  Assign the value to a variable and check it in the debugger; print the length of the string.

Comment: charValue.characters.count = 11

Comment: That is the count of the characteristic value. You need to log the length of `getCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString`

Comment: getCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString.characters.count = 4

Comment: Ok, getCharacteristic.uuid = 2A29; there is 4 character in uuid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147445/discussion-between-paulw11-and-dc2313).

Comment: Sorry, its not work. getCharacteristic.uuid =  Manufacturer Name String

Comment: You can't do anything with `.uuid` in a string context. You have to use `uuid.uuidString` - log this and its length. This is just a string so a string comparison will work. You can also compare `uuid` against `CBUUID(string:"2A29")`

Answer (score 6):

There’s a `uuidString` property on `CBUUID`.

Comment: you are correct, but it is not useful while above function.

Comment: <CBCharacteristic: 0x145351d0, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = <4d455348 54454348 204153>, notifying = NO>

Comment: UUID = Manufacturer Name String, value = 4d455348 54454348 204153;  i need to compare UUID to  Manufacturer Name String.

Comment: How about `getCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString == "Manufacturer Name String"`?

Comment: i need to add characteristic value on lblManufactureName.text, so i need to compare uuid and string.

Comment: when i compare getCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString == "Manufacturer Name String" then  condition was false.

Comment: Log `characteristic.uuid.uuidString` and then you will have the value that you need to compare in your `if`

Comment: "Manufacturer Name String" seems to have has UUID "2A29" according to the following link http://developers-club.com/posts/251937/ , but as mentioned by @Paulw11 log the value or but a break point to get the real value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare UUID against UUID.
Her you compare UUID against name.

CBPeripheral: 0x1c41066f0, identifier = 1CE90EC4-F208-ED69-A4A8-8CF804DDA0D3, name = fxc0c945fc40, state = disconnected

as you can see there is a difference.
try comparing name to name or UUIDS